# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE still adds duplicates even with primary key added

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Im trying to write a function that updates a mysql table if it excist, or creates it if it does not.

My script still creates a new entry instead of updating.

Here is my sql structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `loan` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bank_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `rate` decimal(8,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `loan_0b0af02d` (`bank_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Here is my php script:

```
$item_insert_sql = "INSERT INTO loan(id, bank_id, name, rate) VALUES ('" . $id . "', '" . $bank_id . "', '" . $name . "', '" . $rate . "'), primary key (id), ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (name='$name', rate='$rate')";
$insert_item = mysql_query($item_insert_sql, $db);
```

What do I need to do, to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that it adds duplicates? Primary key won't allow it.

Comment: Please, before you hurt yourself, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This example is terrifyingly vulnerable. You really have no reason to be using the creaky old, deprecated `mysql_query` interface in any new applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your insert statement is incorrect. You can't define primary keys in an insert, and your `on duplicate` syntax is bad as well:

```
INSERT INTO table (... fields ...) VALUES (... values ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY SET field1=value1, field2=value2, etc...
```

If you had even minimal error handling on the query() call, you'd have gotten the error messages:

```
$insert_item = mysql_query($item_insert_sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try the below query:

```
$item_insert_sql = "INSERT INTO loan(id, bank_id, name, rate) VALUES ('" . $id . "', '" . $bank_id . "', '" . $name . "', '" . $rate . "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='$name', rate='$rate';
```